# Whats missing on my Ruby 'Inverse Of' relationship

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I know this topic has been addressed, but I have been at this for 2 days and I'm just stuck. I know inverse of does not create a new query, so should I use another method?

Question: How to set up an 'inverse of' with a has_one, belongs_to situation & same class..

Explanation: A user 'has_one :spouse' and 'belongs_to :spouse_from'. They are inverse of each other.
When a User signs up, they can invite their significant other.
For Example

1. user_a invites & creates user_b
2. user_b.spouse_id is set to user_a.id
3. In a separate method I want to be able to update like..
   user_a.spouse_id = user_a.spouse.id

The only association that works at this point is user_b.spouse.

```
 Class User
  has_one :spouse, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :spouse_id, dependent: :nullify, inverse_of: :spouse_from


  belongs_to :spouse_from, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :spouse_id, inverse_of: :spouse, optional: true
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a step 2b in your initial setup to associate a spouse to `user_a`:

1a) `user_a` invites & creates `user_b`
2a) `user_b.spouse_id` is set to `user_a.id`
2b) `user_a.spouse_id` is set to `user_b.id` (after saving `user_b` to get an ID for it)
3a) ...

This will allow you to later perform the update you wish in another method. The reason that other method update (`user_a.spouse_id = user_a.spouse.id`) doesn't work right now is because `user_a.spouse` is `nil` at the time since that association hasn't been made yet.

However, **and maybe most importantly**, that update you describe (`user_a.spouse_id = user_a.spouse.id`) will never actually accomplish anything, as the right side will always evaluate to the same value that already exists on the left side.

Comment: thank you very much. I am going about it another way, but I will implement it this way as i thought it was the best as well.